# File path cached in dispatcher and rendering a 403 when a sub-set of the file path is requested

Tags: apache, caching, aem, dispatcher

We have rules in the dispatcher saying not to cache a `.pdf`, but allows `.png`. One of the `.pdf` files have a `.png` thumbnail renditions, making the path `/content/a/b/c.pdf/r/s/t.png` in the `jcr` tree structure cacheable.

When user tries to reach the `/a/b/c.pdf` apache returns a `403 - forbidden` status code. The path is valid in the `AEM` app server

I would still like to maintain image caching and resolve the 403.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be to request the asset this way:

`a/b/c.pdf.thumb.48.48.png`

instead of:

`a/b/c.pdf/jcr:content/renditions/cq5dam.thumbnail.48.48.png`

This allows for dispatcher caching, and removes conflict between the metadata and asset.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is next: when image gets cached, dispatcher creates path to it. And one of the folders has name **c.pdf**. Then, when user requests `/content/a/b/c.pdf`, dispatcher sees, that there is a folder with such name and tries to response with it. And it's, of course not a valid pdf file, and even more, not a valid file at all. You can check it easily in request.log - there you will not see request to this pdf, cause dispatcher sent a response this request.

Only one solution comes to my mind (although it's pretty dirty one): you can set up rewrite rule for requests to your pdf files, to add `/jcr:content/renditions/original` tail to path (where pdf content stored actually).

It can look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "^/content/dam" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"jcr_content/renditions" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"jcr:content/renditions" [NC]
RewriteRule ^/content/dam/(.*\.pdf)$ /content/dam/$1/_jcr_content/renditions/original [L,NE,NC]
```

Also, not sure, but flag **R** will be needed for you in the last row.